# Wordpress: Taxonomy counter on Taxonomy List(plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, list, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm using this plugin (Taxonomy List by Muhammad Rehman) and apparently is not longer on develop or support. 
I need to show the main taxonomy (custom from my theme) and the child's taxonomies with the count of elements inside. But after a long trying can't resolve the problem and this is my result 
Actually I'd this schema: 
 
Florida (0) <<<< Must be 3 not 1, because his children's has 1 each one.  
- Jacksonville (1) 
- Miami (1) 
- Saint Petersburg (1) 
 
This must dynamically for each taxonomy.

Comment: You might want to post this on wordpress.stackexchange.com rather than here

Comment: Its on both sides, probably can get a faster answer. Thanks again for you answer and your information.

Comment: Crossposting isn't really considered OK: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Comment: First time on this forum, my apologies.